# Wix Bootstrapper: Product installed fine but never found when uninstalling

Tags: windows-installer, bootstrapper, wix3.11

I have 2 products using Wix Bootstrapper.

Product-A has several dependencies before doing an MSIPackage install of product (per-machine)

Product-B has no dependencies, just MSIPackage install (Example shows .NET 4.8)

Both products install perfectly and can be seen in ARP on completion

Product-A uninstalls perfectly via ARP

Product-B does not

- uninstall removes bootstrapper - no call to product MIS and product no longer in ARP
- Product cannot be uninstalled unless original EXE is run again and Remove is selected when Product MIS is executed
- Log shows the detection of product did not find product.
- Registry between Product-A and Product-B is vastly different despite B being the more simplistic.

This same issue is happening on other products.

If Product-B install fails, even the rollback says the package was not detected, the product remains in registry (aka can't install a new version) but does not show up in ARP.

GUIDs for Bundle, Upgrade and Product are all unique and Bootstrapper project was copied from Product-A

[image: Product-B Bundle]

[image: Product-B Uninstall Log]

[image: Registry Entries]

Comment: The log file suggests `Product-B` was removed by something before uninstalling the bundle. You'll need to look closer at all the involved log files to piece together the order of operations because data is missing for us to look at it.

Comment: Thanks Rob - Nothing else was run to do the uninstall.  I did an install then uninstall and looked at the logs.  Even when I purge registry of any occurrence of the product, this continues to happen.  So if there is something more I can provide, please let me know and I'll do my best to provide it. (Sorry for late reply - I did not get notification of an answer)